# How to loop over a script x times. (using variable for x)

Tags: javascript, json, loops, each

I need to loop certain times over a script:

**The script:**

```
var x = 3
$.get('{{ shop.domain }}/pageX.html?format=json', function (data) {
    //the actual script
});
```

**What I need:**

I need the script to go over this script 3 times:

*First time:*

> .get('{{ shop.domain }}/page1.html?format=json', function (data) { ...

*Second time:*

> .get('{{ shop.domain }}/page2.html?format=json', function (data) { ...

*Third time:*

> .get('{{ shop.domain }}/page3.html?format=json', function (data) { ...

However, when x = 4 I need to go over the script 4 times...

Is this possible? Maybe with an each.. ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Would this do the trick ?

```
var x = 3;
for(i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    $.get('{{ shop.domain }}/page' + i + '.html?format=json', function (data) {
        //the actual script
    });
}
```

If you can't define the function multiple times :

```
function yourFunc(data) {
    // ...
}

var x = 3;
for(i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    $.get('{{ shop.domain }}/page' + i + '.html?format=json', yourFunc);
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. I get the following error: Don't make functions within a loop. The //actual script is a big script which contains functions... :/

Comment: I'm absolutely NOT a JS expert, but why don't you define your function out of the `get()` and pass it to the `get()` ? I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var x = 3
for(var i = 0; i <= x; i++){
    $.get('{{ shop.domain }}/page' + i + '.html?format=json', function (data) {
    //the actual script
    });
}
```

Comment: This didn't work :(. I get the following error: Don't make functions within a loop. The //actual script is a big script which contains functions... :/